# Visual Studio Code freezes after short while "The window is not responding"

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, crash

**Problem:**
I can open VS code and start typing but after ~30s (sometimes minutes) the window freezes showing this message:

[image]

I am using python on a jupyter notebook with only a couple of unspectacular lines which I don't show because I tried different content. Last time it crashed after about 2 min of just import pandas as pd, df = pd.read_csv(path_to_file), print(df)

I think it does not crash when I don't start typing but just wait, at least not as fast

Yesterday everything was still fine. Today with the same setup not.

**System information:**

Windows 11 home
The only VS extensions installed are
Python v2022.7.11331006
Pylance v2022.5.1
Jupyter v2022.5.1001351004
Jupyter Keymap v1.0.0
Jupyter Notebook Renderers
Which other information is needed to help?

**Attempts (not resolving the problem):**

1. Work from a different folder with a new file/code
2. Disabling extensions (but notebook will not work without some)
3. Uninstall/reinstall same version (x64-1.67.1)
4. Uninstall/install previous version (1.66.1)
5. Unistall/install insider version (x64-1.68.0-insider)
6. Disable all online connecting services in VS, disconnecting from internet.
7. Rollback of last windows patch update
8. Delete backup folders in %AppData%/Code/..
9. Graphic card is up-to-date
10. I am reluctant to disable stuff that makes the dell xps faster (and expensive)

Comment: I am facing the same issue on Linux (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the latest Pylance extension. You can revert to earlier Pylance extension to solve the problem. This problem will be fixed in a new version in a few days according to the [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/149546).

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast answer! At least, now I only wasted one day and not more. Incredible that this version is just left out threre, potentially screwing up millions of users, and not immediately pulled back or at least ammended with a warning to users, to save them from loosing hours searching whats wrong.